# I am using repeater to display data from database and using checkboxes.But I am not getting values of multiple selected checkboxes..please help

Tags: asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function collect() {
                alert('in function');
                var adds = new Array();
                alert(adds);
        for (var i = 0; i < control.getElementByName("box").value; i++) {
            alert('innn function');
            if (control.getElementByName("box[i]").checked)
                adds = control.getElementByName("box[i]").value;
        }
        alret(adds);
        //window.location="/collect.aspx?value="+adds;
        control.getElementByName("Label1").appendChild(adds);

        } 
</script>
```

calling function on button:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="collect() "/>
```

Comment: Will `control.getElementByName("box[i]")` even work? It appears to me that you are searching for a control with the exact name "box[i]". Instead of "box[2]" and "box[5]" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
for (var i = 0; i < control.getElementByName("box").value; i++) {
   alert('innn function');
   if (control.getElementByName("box[i]").checked)
   adds = control.getElementByName("box[i]").value;
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < control.getElementByName("box").value; i++) {
   alert('innn function');
   if (control.getElementByName("box[" + i + "]").checked)
   adds = control.getElementByName("box[" + i + "]").value;
}
```